# Java 8 Arraylist hugeCapacity(int) implementation

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm reading the documentation for how `ArrayList`s in Java are grown. I don't understand why the [`hugeCapacity(int minCapacity)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.hugeCapacity%28int%29) method chooses to return either `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE`.

From how `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` is defined in the class,

```
244 |     private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

It's almost the same as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` except off by the size of one integer (`32 bits`).

```
264 |     private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
265 |         if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
266 |             throw new OutOfMemoryError();
267 |         return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
268 |             Integer.MAX_VALUE :
269 |             MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
270 |     }
```

Can anyone tell me what the subtle difference is in returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` versus `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE`? Either way, shouldn't an `OutOfMemoryError` occur?

Comment: The answer is right there in the comment above MAX_ARRAY_SIZE:  

"The maximum size of array to allocate. Some VMs reserve some header words in an array. Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit".  

Meaning: If we can avoid OutOfMemory on some VMs, we will, otherwise, allocate Integer.MAX_VALUE, and succeed if you're lucky (depending on the VM)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The maximal array size is limited to some number which varies across different JVMs and usually is slightly less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So allocating the array of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements you will have `OutOfMemoryError` on most of JVMs even if you have enough memory to do it. `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` assumes to be valid array size on the most of existing JVMs. So when `ArrayList` size approaches to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (for example, you have more than 1_500_000_000 elements and need to enlarge an array), it's enlarged to this `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE`, so it can be  successfully performed (assuming you have enough memory). Only if number of elements exceeds `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE`, the `ArrayList` tries to allocate an array of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements (which will likely to fail on most of JVMs, but *may* succeed on some of them). This way you can safely add elements up to `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` on almost any JVM and only after that will have problems.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle's implementation (Java 8 update 31):

```
/**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate.
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

They return   *(2 <sup>31</sup> - 1) - 8*   to make sure their code do not create `OutOfMemoryError` when executed by another VM implementation.